# How to debug Unfortunately MyApp has stopped? Works on emulator, not on phone

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, gps

I am developing app in Xamarin, which is tracking current location of user on the phone.

When I test app on the emulator it works with no issues, when I deploy it on the phone app works for 10 seconds, and I can see GPS icon blinking in the top. After 5 seconds GPS icon stops blinking and app crashes with "Unfortunately MyApp has stopped".

How can I debug this on the phone, since it works on emulator? I reckon it is some threading problem.

Got stack trace, SIGSEGV fatal error:
http://pastebin.com/Bxt68ikj

My code:
**Timer.cs**

```
 public delegate void TimerCallback(object state);

    public sealed class Timer : CancellationTokenSource, IDisposable
    {
        public int DueTime { get; set; }
        public int Period { get; set; }

        public void Start(TimerCallback callback, object state)
        {
            Task.Delay(DueTime, Token).ContinueWith(async (t, s) =>
            {
                var tuple = (Tuple<TimerCallback, object>)s;

                while (true)
                {
                    if (IsCancellationRequested)
                        break;
                    Task.Run(() => tuple.Item1(tuple.Item2));
                    await Task.Delay(Period);
                }

            }, Tuple.Create(callback, state), CancellationToken.None,
               TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously | TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
               TaskScheduler.Default);
        }

        public new void Dispose() { base.Cancel(); }
    }
```

**TimerLocationService.cs**

```
public class TimerLocationService : ITimerLocationService
{
    private Timer _timer;

    public void Start(TimerCallback callback, object state)
    {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.DueTime = 60000;
        _timer.Period = 60000;
        _timer.Start(callback, null);
    }

    public void SetTimer(int dueTime, int period)
    {
        _timer.DueTime = dueTime;
        _timer.Period = period;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _timer.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**MainPageViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private readonly IAccountService _accountService;
        private readonly IGeolocatorService _geolocatorService;
        private readonly ITimerLocationService _timerLocationService;

        public MainPageViewModel(IAccountService accountService, IGeolocatorService geolocatorService, ITimerLocationService timerLocationService)
        {
            _accountService = accountService;
            _geolocatorService = geolocatorService;
            _timerLocationService = timerLocationService;
            LabelUsername = GetUsername();
            GetCurrentCoordinates();
            _timerLocationService.Start(SendCoordinates, null);
        }

        private string _logoutButtonText = "Login";

        public string LogoutButtonText
        {
            get { return _logoutButtonText; }
            set
            {
                _logoutButtonText = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _labelUsername = "Login";

        public string LabelUsername
        {
            get { return _labelUsername; }
            set
            {
                _labelUsername = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _labelCoordinate = "0";
        public string LabelCoordinate
        {
            get { return _labelCoordinate; }
            set
            {
                _labelCoordinate = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ICommand LogoutCommand => new MethodInvokerCommand(Logout);
        public ICommand TimerCommand => new MethodInvokerCommand(SetTimer);

        private void SetTimer()
        {
            _timerLocationService.SetTimer(10000, 10000);
        }

        private void Logout()
        {
            _accountService.Logout();
        }

        private string GetUsername()
        {
            return _accountService.GetUsername();
        }

        private async void GetCurrentCoordinates()
        {
            var position = await _geolocatorService.GetPositionAsync();

            LabelCoordinate = position.Latitude + ", " + position.Longitude;

            await _geolocatorService.SendPositionAsync();
        }

        private async void SendCoordinates(object args)
        {
            await _geolocatorService.SendPositionAsync();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could start by putting some try/catch constructions in there and just pop up a messagebox to pin-point where it happens

Comment: I added stack trace, while connecting device via usb and using debug. Doesn't even start on the phone in debug mode.

Comment: `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.` It says it's missing some file(s)?

Comment: I understand that, but what can I do here?

Comment: Did you check if that dll is referenced under your project References?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a timer... At all?

You can subscribe to the event raised when the location changes and just react to that.  Polling through timers like this is very 1990's.

Comment: I don't want to send when location changes, that would be sending every second. I want to send every 1 minute no matter of location.